# Unable to load a svg image from url in ios app

Tags: ios, swift, url

I am trying to display svg images from remote url. I have used SwiftSVG library to display the image. But instead of image a round circle is displaying. Please check screenshot:
[image]

I am using following code to display the image in UITableViewCell:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSVG

class AssetsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var assetNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var assetSymbolLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var assetAveragePrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var assetImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    func set(cryptoCurrency: CryptoCurrency) {
        let svgURL = URL(string: cryptoCurrency.icon)!
        
        let hammock = UIView(SVGURL: svgURL) { (svgLayer) in
            svgLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.52, green:0.16, blue:0.32, alpha:1.00).cgColor
            svgLayer.resizeToFit(CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 60, height: 60))
        }
        addSubview(hammock)
        
        assetImageView.loadImageUsingCache(withUrl: cryptoCurrency.icon)
        assetNameLabel.text = cryptoCurrency.name
        assetSymbolLabel.text = cryptoCurrency.symbol
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Comment: Show all relevant lines of code.  Where is the code for your table view?

Comment: I have added my complete tableviewcell code, in tableview there is nothing much, I am doing everything from Storyboard, only using the delegate methods

Comment: You are adding hammock to the table view cell itself with `addSubview(hammock)`.  Create a UIImage object from hammock and set it as assetImageView.image.